# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

Evening all,

I am having an issue with this script and i'm hoping one of you fine programmers could let me know where the error is.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("tutorial") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Data Base"
$query = "SELECT * FROM forr1";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['input1'];


?>
```

**The Output**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Output.php on line 7
```

I must be missing something significant because no matter how i try and rework it i get the same error.

Thanks for your time

Ben

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on your `echo` line

Comment: down votes kinda unnecessary

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Missing semi-colon on the line prior:

```
echo "Connected to Data Base"
```

Terminate the statement:

```
echo "Connected to Data Base";
```

Comment: Thanks man wow i feel silly i really need to go to bed :/

Comment: I will give you Correct answer tick soon as the accept time finish's

Comment: @bennyboy Plenty of time for that, glad you're sorted.

Comment: still makes sense as common error